# Why is TokenCallback in stripe not working?

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement TokenCallback and CardUtils in my app and i get the error "cannot resolve symbol TokenCallback". Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong.

I already have implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:14.0.0' in my app's build.gradle

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That TokenCallback was deprecated and removed. It was replaced with `ApiResultCallback<Token>` as shown here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/36a5e8fcbd3aefe1be7598143d68890ed1c101c5/MIGRATING.md#migrating-from-versions--1100

For reference, this is the section of the example that uses that callback: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/f6bbb10c1c5048818ae65fb0a968c2538a4a060f/example/src/main/java/com/stripe/example/activity/CreateCardTokenActivity.kt#L136